# scope route rails 3.1, how does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this in my routes.rb

```
scope '/admin' do
  root :to => 'home#index'

  resources :posts do
    scope :information, :controller => 'information' do
      match 'description'
    end
  end
end
```

This give me

```
post_description        /admin/posts/:post_id/description(.:format) {:action=>"description", :controller=>"information"}
```

It leads to the controller that i want, though i need to have **information** in my url like this:

```
/admin/posts/:post_id/information/description(.:format)
```

I have tried using namespace instead but that need a mapstructure **information/information**

How should i accomplish what i want, which route strategy should i use?
I've read [Rails routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) 2 times, and still I'm not able to figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: If i do`match "information/description", :controller => :information, :action => :description` inside `resources :posts do`everything is correct. But i have like 6-7 actions i want to route to so i want to "scope" it to information.

Comment: Did you try namespace :information without the addition of :controller => 'information'? This should still route to your information controller, but won't give you the CRUD routes.

Comment: Yes i did, that did not route to information_controller. If i do `namespace :information`, it routes to: `:controller => "information/posts"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
scope '/admin' do
  root :to => 'home#index'

  resources :posts do
    resource :information, :only => [] do
      get 'description'
    end
  end
end
```

[EDIT]

More REST-like: The REST/resourceful thing to do would be to build resources that would deliver the information. So the resource `information` would give all info on GET. If the description is the actual resource you are getting, then it should be `posts/:id/description`. If a description is a resource linked to information, then indeed your path is as specified. Now what we do in that case is build our resource more Atom-like, with links to the related items. E.g.

```
<post>
  <title>....</title>
  <content> ... </content>
  <link rel="'self' href='link-to-self' />
  <link rel='information' href='link-to-information' />
</post>
```

When building REST-API we consider it a smell if the urls get very long and nested-nested-nested. Providing the links also allow for exploration of the API.

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Yes that would work, but then i would still have the rest routes (create, edit etz). And since I'm not going to use them that feels wrong. Thank you for the fast reply though

Comment: You can block methods, using the `:only => [...]` option. But not sure if that works if the array is empty. I added a possible alternative approach, not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: That works thank you. Although the url helper for this is `description_post_information_path` which is not ultimate imo. And it feels like a hack, or is it just me? And how would i use this helper, `description_post_information_path(@post)` is not working.

Comment: Sry, `description_post_information_path(@post)` does work, still feels like a hack though.